# Hide :focus if user :hover?

Tags: css

I have this in my css based off of [line25 navigation tutorial](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-trendy-flat-style-nav-menu-in-css/).

I added this addition to my css and would like that when a user hovers over a menu icon, it wipes away the :focus span (icon text description) and only displays :hover span text at the moment. How can that be achieved?

```
nav ul li a:focus span {
    display: block;
}

nav ul li a:hover span {
    display: block;
}
```

Currently the :hover text and :focus text jumble on each other.

Here is the [codepen on the exact thing](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/OWXGRR).

Comment: Could you provide an code-example on codepen, jsfiddle or Stackoverflow Snippet etc.? Also I am not sure what you want exactly.  The spans overlap, because both of them are visible? You could you a solid background color and a higher z-index on the span to overlay the previous one. Don't know which way around you like.

Comment: can you use jquery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things you can do:

First Idea: Put the :hover on always on top with a solid background-color.

```
nav ul li a:hover span, nav ul li a:focus span {
  display: block;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;

}
nav ul li a:hover span {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Or you could hide the focus one as soon as you hover over the list:

```
nav ul:hover li a:focus span {
  display: none;
}
#navbar-lg ul li a:hover span, nav ul li a:focus span {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Stupid question, but in the second example, line 1, what is that really saying?

Comment: I used the second option, but I am hoping you will read the prior comment.

Comment: @user2899444 `nav ul:hover li a:focus span` selects the span that is inside an a element which has the pseudo-class :focus applied. But only if you hover the list, which is inside nav.

Comment: Where is a good resource to learn/see more of this kind of topic (second option format)?